# How to find convergents/approximate ratios for 3 (or more) numbers - (3 number Euclidean algorithm?)

Tags: continued-fractions

It is easy to find approximate ratios between 2 numbers by using the Euclidean algorithm to calculate continued fractions. However I can not find a method to do this for 3 numbers.

I have tried a shared Euclidean algorithm (dividing by the lowest of the 3 remainders each time) and it did not come close to any approximate ratios found by simply testing each denominator in turn.

The first problem is that I do not know what a canonical measure of error would be, as there are 3 pairs of ratios with differing errors that can be calculated.

After that, I do not know how to adjust the euclidean algorithm to successivly approximate 3 ratios simultaneously. The perfect fit for a particular ratio (found by the Euclidean algorithm) often has a high error for the other ratios.

I have found published convergents of 3 or more ratios as integer sequences at oeis.org/A060528 related to the even/equal tempering of musical instruments and the desired ratios of muical intervals. However in the description the author explains that this was done through testing nearly 7 million successive possibilities, rather than an algorithm as is used for simple continued fractions.

If there is no solution, is this known to be impossible, a known "hard" problem, or just something mathematicians haven't cared about?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm

Comment: Thanks for the link. So lots of famous mathematicians tried and failed until a few decades ago. I read up about the algorithm, I did not understand it at all, and 64 bit numbers do not have enough precision... so I guess I'm not doing it with my students! It is implemented in Sage. I'm glad mathematics does not need to be understood to be used...

Comment: Good. as with LLL, it can help solve problems that are not what comes to mind when you see a description. Try this thing: http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard